# How to rewrite LINQ-based code as a for loop

Tags: c#, enums

I'm using the following code:

```
public class Card
{

  public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit)
  {
    this.Rank = rank;
    this.Suit = suit;
  }

  public Rank Rank { get; private set; }
  public Suit Suit { get; private set; }

}

public enum Rank : byte
{
  Ace   =  1,
  Two   =  2,
  Three =  3,
  Four  =  4,
  Five  =  5,
  Six   =  6,
  Seven =  7,
  Eight =  8,
  Nine  =  9,
  Ten   = 10,
  Jack  = 11,
  Queen = 12,
  King  = 13,
}

public enum Suit : byte
{
  Club    = 1, // Klavers
  Diamond = 2, // Ruiten
  Heart   = 3, // Harten
  Spades  = 4  // Schoppen
}

public class Deck 
{
    private List<Card> deck = new List<Card>(52);

    public Deck()
    {
        this.FillStack();
    }

    public void FillStack() 
    {
        this.deck.Clear();
        this.deck.AddRange(
          Enumerable.Range(1,4)
          .SelectMany( s =>
             Enumerable.Range(1, 13)
             .Select( n => new Card( (Rank)n , (Suit)s ) )
           )
        ) ;
    }
```

Can I replace the LINQ-based code in `FillStack` with equivalent code based on a `for` loop? The goal is to make the code easier to understand and extend for those who are less familiar with LINQ.

Comment: According to your question, it is hard to believe that *you* have written that linq that fills the deck.

Comment: Indeed i did not , i'm learning.. Also i never told said i did , i just editted some stuff,  i'm getting comfortable with Csharp but LINQ is a bit of a problem. I'm not asking for any negative critism either just help from the more advanced programmers on SO

Comment: Jelman, if you are not comfortable with linq, then don't use it. Classical `for-loops` are enough. BTW: What kind of critisism you expect is not important. When you ask a question here, you may get any of them.

Comment: I know , but the only thing i'm asking for is help.IMO it's pretty unfair to get attacked right away .. I'm just trying to be friendly and learn from the more knowledged persons around here.. Not to get minus reputation right away

Comment: Jelman, but this is how SO works.. If someone thinks a question/answer is bad, he votes down it. Either you have to live with it or not ask here.

Comment: Okay then, sorry for the hassle.
Is it possible to explain me how the For loop can be used to add those properties in Enumerables?

Comment: If LINQ is a problem for you right now, simply don't use it. The answer to "can this LINQ be converted to a looping structure," is always going to be "yes". It *does* sound like the edits to your question have removed your original intent, but your original intent was/is incredibly unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a good example of how not to use the LINQ helper methods. There is no advantage over a plain old and far more readable

```
for (int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
  for (int n = 1; n <= 13; n++)
    this.deck.Add(new Card((Rank)n, (Suit)s));
```

The LINQ version could be made somewhat more readable though: here's how it could look when not attempting to stuff it all into a single expression.

```
var suits = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
var ranks = Enumerable.Range(1, 13);
var cards =
  from s in suits
  from n in ranks
  select new Card((Rank)n, (Suit)s);
this.deck.AddRange(cards);
```

This should be easier to understand, but it still means pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say something like this

```
public void FillStack()
{
  this.deck.Clear() ;
  this.deck.AddRange(
    Enumerable
    .Range(0,52)
    .Select( n => new Card( (Rank)(1+n%13), (Suit)(1+n/13) ) )
  ) ;
  return ;
}
```

Or even

```
public void FillStack()
{
  this.deck.Clear() ;
  foreach ( Rank rank in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rank)) )
  {
    foreach( Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)) )
    {
      Card card = new Card( rank , suit ) ;
      this.deck.Add( card ) ;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: The first of these is not good for readability, and that's what the focus of the question is on. Your second looks like a useful suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is to replace the LINQ query with for loop so it's easier to understand. That's fair enough. But since you are learning it's worth to understand the query itself. Then you will be able to replace it yourself or, better yet, you will be comfortable enough with it to leave it there.

Let's break it down and try to explain it line by line:

```
[1]    this.deck
[2]            .AddRange(
[3]                Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
[4]                .SelectMany(s => 
[5]                    Enumerable.Range(1, 13)
[6]                    .Select(n => 
[7]                        new Card((Rank)n, (Suit)s))));
```

Start from the line #3 `Enumerable.Range(1,4)` - the method returns range of numbers from `1` to `4`. So we have a collection `1, 2, 3, 4`. In line #4 we access this collection item by item. So we actually iterate over the items. Each item is denoted by a variable `s` - you can use it to access the items. The same mechanism is repeated to create iteration from 1 to 13 (lines #5 and #6). The items in the second iteration are accessed by variable `n`.

Bigger picture - we iterate from 1 to 4 and inside that we iterate from 1 to 13. Now, in line #7 we create a `Card` and the numbers from both iterations - denoted as `n` and `s` - are used in the constructor of the class. Because we iterate through number from 1 to 4 and inside that from 1 to 13 we will get all the combinations: (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (2,1) (2,2) and so on. Each item from the combination will create a card. So it will result in a collection of cards. And now go back to line #2 `AddRange` method is responsible for adding this range of cards to the `deck` collection.

Hope this will help to understand the query and replace it with more imperative code.

Comment: If you are leaning LINQ then, contrary to the recommendations in comments, I would try to write as much code using LINQ as possible. Most of standard loops and indeed many other operations can be replace by LINQ. Figuring out how to do it is a great exercise.